# Как удалить дубликаты строк textarea (jq)

Tags: html, jquery

Есть:

```
<textarea>
line
hi
line2
more words
hi
</textarea>
<div id='button'>кнопка</div>
```

хочу что бы по нажатию #button удалился дубликат `hi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");

const clear = () => {

  let rows = textarea.value.split("\n");
  
  rows = rows.filter((value, index) => !(rows.indexOf(value) != index))

  textarea.value = rows.join("\n");

}

button.addEventListener("click", clear)
```

```html
<textarea>
line
hi
line2
more words
hi
</textarea>
<div id='button'>кнопка</div>
```